# GL/glfw.h does not exist

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone, fedora

I'm using Fedora 17 and compiling cocos2d-x.  I've got an error at the compilation when I'm launching `./make-all-linux-project.sh`.

G++ tells me that GL/glfw.h does not exist and then I `yum install glew` but it wasn't solved. So how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The package glew is actually the OpenGL Extension Wrangler. In this case your error is referring to a different package - GLFW. The problem with the build script you are trying to run is that it was made for deb-based systems, not rpm-based systems like Fedora. What's going to make this more difficult is that if you use YUM to download glfw and glfw-devel, they are not the version Cocos2d-x needs, so the build will fail. What you will need to do is first download a legacy version of glfw from Git Hub and build it from source.

git clone https://github.com/glfw/glfw-legacy.git

Once you build this package, you will need to modify the Cocos2d-x make file: $COCOS_ROOT/cocos2dx/proj.linux/cocos2dx.mk to include the legacy headers and also link to the legacy lib. The build should go smoothly after this, assuming all of your other dependencies are installed. You can refer to a blog post I put together for the detailed instructions: http://voidfuture.wordpress.com/2013/10/08/building-cocos2d-x-on-rhel-fedora-centos-linux/